# What Size Value Should Be Used When Adding a Parameter of SqlDbType.Text?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2017

I am updating project code to maximize the re-use of SQL Server Query Plans when querying the database from our C# application.

We use ADO.NET, and we are converting all queries to use SqlParameters.

When adding a parameter whose value will be set into a table column of type TEXT, we are using:

```
[...]

command.Parameters.Add("@MyParamName", SqlDBType.Text, someSize).Value = paramValue;

[...]
```

If our goal is to get this kind of statement to re-use query plans, what size should I use in place of "someSize" above?

Is there a special value that would provide the best chance of successfully getting SQL Server to re-use the query plan every time this code is called?

---

**UPDATE**

Per comment from @Sean-Lange Microsoft is deprecating NTEXT, TEXT and IMAGE... an excerpt from [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) he provided in the comments below:

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a
>   future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: You should not be using that type in the first place. The text datatype has been deprecated for close to 15 years now in favor of varchar(max). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @SeanLange, Want to put that as an answer, I would accept - and my tech lead just said he usually changes any Text columns to varchar(max) when he sees them.

Comment: I would also advise to prefer specifying `varchar(8000)` (or even a lower value) instead of `varchar(max)` whenever possible. The `varchar(max)`  comes with a performance price a lot of times.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - this perspective seems odd to me. Obviously there can be some latitude and room for negotiation *at times* but often if we're picking `varchar(max)` in the first place, it's because there's some operational constraint that rules out a low bound. (And ignoring for the time being data "modellers" who just always use the largest available data type to "future proof" their designs)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The data "modellers" you are ignoring is the exact reason why I've posted my previous comment in the first place :-). Of course if you might need more than 8000 chars or 4000 Unicode chars you have to use `max`. That's why I've written "whenever possible".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text datatype was deprecated in sql server 2005 in favor of varchar(max). You can read more about that datatype here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017